# Best practice for saving new model instance in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to DRF and I can't wrap my head around where to save new model instances when I POST to my endpoints.

I need to overwrite my `def create()` method because I'm managing nested objects in my queries.
I've noticed that I can save new instances from the model Serializer ( `def create(self, validated_data)`) but also from the associated class view ( `def create(self, request)`)

What's the best practice here? I'm pretty sure I'm confusing major concepts, please indulge me!

Comment: first, some code would help understand your problem better.
other than that, if I understood correctly, your'e asking where to override default create with DRF?

for that Django's best practice is slim views and heavy models and serializers.
if you'll look at the source code for create method in views you'll see it's just calling the serializer and validating data and then creating, so, ideally, you should only overide the create method on your serializer.

Comment: @yovelcohen that's exactly what I was wondering, it can be a bit confusing when starting with DRF.